# Scramble per letter using javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can I scramble the words per letter?
My code scramble the whole words...
I can't seem to change it per letter. Since I'm new to Vue.js
I'm using Vue.js in here.

```
const sampleText1 = 'インバウント'

const characters =
  'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
const charactersLength = characters.length

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            sam01: sampleText1,
        }
    },
    setup() {
        const texts = reactive({
            text1: sampleText1,
        })
        
        const scrambleText = (text, name) => ({ progress }) => {
            if (progress === 100) {
            texts[name] = text
            } else if (Math.floor(progress) % 20 === 0) {
            texts[name] = text.replace(
                /./g,
                characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength))
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKEnb.gif)

[expected output](https://im3.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-3-71653d37a0db.gif)

Comment: sample input and expected output to clarify your question would be awesome

Comment: expected output [expected output](https://im3.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-3-71653d37a0db.gif)
the current ouput [current ouput](https://im3.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-3-fc4bff45b8bc.gif)

Comment: don't mind the moving animation. just the scramble

Comment: no, could you put the expected output in the question, not as an image - because those images mean nothing without example input

Comment: im using vue.js so it might be difficult to explain the input

Comment: well, what type of values do you use to call `scrambleText`  ... what is `texts`, it's not declared in your code

Comment: i updated my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the replacement as a function instead of single string which will invoke for each match.

```js
...
  texts[name] = text.replace(
    /./g,
    () => characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength))
  )
...
```